# How can i make a link from a leaflet.js map?

Tags: leaflet

I'm not at all a programmer, so I politely ask for your patience.

I maintain a leaflet.js webpage with a bunch of wms services and stuff I use in my daily work. However not all data are that easily rendered. There's no api for oblique aerial photos of my country, but the photos are available on a website, where the map-position is in the URL. Like this:

> https://skraafoto.kortforsyningen.dk/oblivisionjsoff/index.aspx?project=Denmark&lon=10.2027929&lat=56.1377927

So I was wondering. How would you get a coordinate from leaflet, transform it into a URL, and open the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a pop-up

```
var popup = L.popup();
    function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent('<a href=https://skraafoto.kortforsyningen.dk/oblivisionjsoff/index.aspx?project=Denmark&lon=' + e.latlng.lng.toString() + '&lat=' + e.latlng.lat.toString() + ' target=_blank>Skråfotos</a>')
            .openOn(map);
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```